# load image from a directory copy it to application folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi all is it possible to load the image form the path which is stored in database. I will have the file path saved in my database as `C:\Documents\filename.jpg`. Is it possible to load the image from this path. I tried some code as follows to load the image based on some condition

```
function loadImage(imgName) {
var vPath = '';
if (imgName != null && imgName!= "") {
    // my code to retrieve the image path
    vPath = imagepath from db
    return vPath;
}
else
    return "appImages/NoImage.png";
}
```

But this is not loading the image as per expected. but the later part if image is null I am able to show the image as it is with in the application. So can some one help me how to load the image from the path obtained.

Or can I copy the file from the path obtained to the localpath i.e to some temp folder with in the application so that I can load the image from that path

Answer (score 1):

to load the image, you need a valid url, not a physical path.

If your server can serve the image, then you need the database to store the url of the image, not: 
'C:\Documents\filename.jpg. '

but something like 'http://mydomain.com/Documents\filename.jpg';

or, client side code can covert the string by reversion the slashes and replacing 'c:\' with 
'http://'

if your server can't serve the file from the location that its in, then you need to copy it to where it can serve the file, suing server code

OR
web service function on server receives 'C:\Documents\filename.jpg.' as param, opens the file server side, and return the bytes of image.
then url to the service on the server can access the image.

Comment: But at localhost you can use direct path like `C:\Documents\filename.jpg`. In Windows it works great.

Answer (score 0):

For coping images with JavaScript you need to use `ajax` query to `php` script, which will be copy image to app folder and return path to this image back to JS script.